# Statistical query model algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms

Can you give me examples of machine learning algorithms which learn from the statistical properties of the dataset not the individual observations itself i.e. employ the statistical query model?

Comment: Is that the statistical query model of Kearns (1998) http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/293347.293351 ? If so, sorry, i'd never even heard of it before.

Comment: @onestop yes it is.

Comment: flagged this as too localized since it seems to be based around one paper, that the only commenter hadn't even heard of.  Not to mention the question is rather vague and open ended.

Answer (score 1):

[The Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) is a bayesian filter that is also a machine learning algorithm.  It learns from the several components that include the statistics of the data it's tracking.